# Run Multiple Classes of java in jgrasp

Tags: java, jgrasp

I created a server client programm using sockets in java in netbeans but now i want to run it in jgrasp  IDE but jgrasp is not allowing me two run both the classes parllely

Comment: That's not something many tools would allow you to do on one machine; have you considered trying it on two? I realize this may not be ideal. I'm not that familiar with jgrasp, I know you **can** do it in eclipse. And intellij.

Comment: You dont run multiple instance of app from IDE easily, it is IDE's feature, what you can do is configure argument to you jar application and run jar seperately with new server port